# NTP Client Library. Set sync provider pointing to public class function. Possible?

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, library, esp8266, time

I am trying to develop a NTP client library for ESP8266/Arduino to make adding NTP sync an easier task.

Basically, I've thought about a constructor as **`NTPClient(String host, int interval);`** and a **`NTPClient.begin()`** function to register sync function.

My problem is with that registering.

I have a public function: **`time_t ntpClient::getNtpTime()`** that connects to NTP server, decodes the response and returns a `time_t` variable.

Then, inside **`boolean ntpClient::begin()`** function I try to run **`setSyncProvider(ntpClient::getNtpTime)`**. I've also tried to use **`setSyncProvider(this->getNtpTime)`**.

I get a compile error here:

```
ntpClient.cpp:In member function 'boolean ntpClient::begin()
ntpClient.cpp:79:39: error: cannot convert 'ntpClient::getNtpTime' from type 'time_t (ntpClient::)() {aka long int (ntpClient::)()}' to type 'getExternalTime {aka long int (*)()}
  setSyncProvider(ntpClient*:getNtpTime)
Error compiling project sources
```

What could I do to allow registering this function as sync provider to hide NTP internals to my sketches?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your code...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What could I do to allow registering this function as sync provider to hide NTP internals to my sketches?

The function should be a static member function. A "normal" member function does not have the right prototype as there is a hidden parameter ("this").

```
static time_t getNtpTime();
```

To solve this you need a [single-ton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) (an instance of the client class) that the static function can use.

```
class NTPClient {
public:
   NTPClient() ...
   {
     ...
     s_client = this;
   }
   time_t getNtpTime();
   ...
   static time_t getNtpTime() ( return (s_client->getNtpTime()); }
   ...
protected:
   static NTPClient* s_client;
   ...
}; 
...
NTPClient::s_client = NULL;
...
NTPClient ntpClient;
...
setSyncProvider(NTPClient::getNtpTime)
```

Alternatively a global function and a known instance:

```
class NTPClient { ... };
extern NTPClient ntpClient;
...
time_t getNtpTime() { return (ntpClient.getNtpTime()); } 
...
setSyncProvider(getNtpTime)
```

Cheers!

Comment: It was that, thank you. I've tried to change `getNtpTime()` to static but doing that makes impossible to access variables and non static funcions. So, the only possibility I see is adding a static funcion in main program that wraps a non static `ntpClient.getNtpTime()`.  I'm not an expert C++ programmer at all. Do you think there is any other possibility? I'll upload my code to github and publish here the link.

Comment: That is what the last line was all about. You need an instance that the static member function may use. For instance, add a static ntpClient pointer to the class and assign it in the constructor. The static member function can then use that to call the implementation.

Comment: I've uploaded my code to [https://github.com/gmag11/NtpClient](https://github.com/gmag11/NtpClient). I'll check the link about single-ton design pattern.

Comment: Please see the update code example above. Cheers!

Comment: I got it working finally. I've done sync provider registering in setup() function. I will try to add a begin member function in a later moment. Last version is on GitHub. Thank you for your recommendation about singleton.

Comment: Great! Here is a link to my own implementation of NTP for Cosa. It uses a Socket interface so there is no need to implement it again for WiFi or other IP devices as long as the device driver implements the Socket interface. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa-NTP. Please note that it does not implement clock synchronization. That would be done by the Cosa Clock class.